# Django image does not display

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm new to Django, and I encounter this problem with images that I can't solve... The path is like this: Django-Project, Profiles, static, media, profileIMG.

Here is my model.

```
    from django.db import models
    from accounts.models import NewUser


    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(NewUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='Untitled.png', upload_to='profileIMG')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

settings.py

```
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    ]

    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include

    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns = [
                      path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                      path('', include('accounts.urls')),
                      path('', include('profiles.urls')),
                  ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

form.py

```
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from .models import UserProfile


    class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = UserProfile
            fields = '__all__'
            exclude = ['user']
```

view.py function

```
    @login_required(login_url='login_user')
    def profiles(request):
        indexID = request.user
        form = ProfileForm(instance=indexID)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=indexID)
            if form.is_valid():
                messages.success(request, ("The file is valid"))
                form.save()
           else:
               messages.success(request, ("Invalid File."))

        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, "profiles/profiles.html", context)
```

And my template profiles.html.

```
    {% load static %}
    <div class="main">
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <img class="profile-pic" src="{{ request.user.UserProfile.profile_pic.url         
    }}"/>
                <p>This is profile page </p>
                <span>Hello, {{request.user}} </span>
                <p>{{ form }}</p>
                <input class="imgBTN" type="submit" name="imgBTN">
                <span><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></span>
            </form>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to select an image dynamically, not just adding the name of the picture.
Does anyone know how to fix this, please?

Comment: How are you running your Django app? Is this in a production server? Or are you using `./manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Also what happens when you load the profile page? Will you show a screenshot please?

Comment: It's recommended if you give `/` at the end of `upload_to` like `upload_to="ProfileIMG/"`, you can see here, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your views all of method is post, nothing get method to get data from database

try add `profile = UserProfile.object.get()`

and then add context `'profile':profile`

so the full view.py like this

```
    @login_required(login_url='login_user')
    def profiles(request):
        indexID = request.user
        profile = UserProfile.object.get(user=indexID)
        form = ProfileForm(instance=indexID)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=indexID)
            if form.is_valid():
                messages.success(request, ("The file is valid"))
                form.save()
           else:
               messages.success(request, ("Invalid File."))

        context = {'form': form, 'profile':profile}
        return render(request, "profiles/profiles.html", context)
```

good luck and keep coding

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't access the UserProfile.object.get, it says that I have to create an object variable in the model. Sorry for taking so long, I've been dealing with another monster bug. I totally forget to mention that my user model is not an extension of User, it's a total custom model extended from AbstractUserModel, so for some reason UserProfile doesn't link to it directly. When I create the table for the user profile and I try to upload a picture from the website, it remains empty. But if I try to post it from the admin page, it gives me the option to link the UserProfile ...

Comment: ... So, it gives me the option to link the UserProfile to the NewUser model from the admin dashboard. When I do it this way, the database gets populated with the NewUser primary key and the picture itself.

Comment: Here is a GitHub link to the project. https://github.com/RazzTazz28/Django-Atlas.git

Comment: I mean the UserProfile table gets populated, not the whole database...You know what I mean...

Comment: i will forking your repo and try to fix the bug

Comment: Don't bother too much. Just if you have a suggestion at first glance. I don't want to waste your time with my projects. Thank you very much for your suggestion yesterday! After I finish with another registration bug, I'm going to come back and analyze the problem again head to toe.

Comment: no problem bro, I happen to be free